# Visual Studio 2015 Code Snippet?

Tags: visual-studio-2015, code-snippets

I'm following this [video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=yCAfNb1KR8A) to create custom snippet and recall them when I want with an easy shortcut.

But once I select my code and I do "Export as snippet" in VS2015 it just open File Dialog to Add new Item to the project. I can't see any Snippet Manager.

Where am I wrong? I don't have any .snippet file type there.

Comment: Must be a problem with your Snippet Designer extension - have you restarted VS?  If so, maybe uninstall/re-install.  My "Export as Snippet" takes the selected code straight into the Snippet Manager as shown in the video.

Comment: Mine not! Yes I've restarted VS2015 after installing it. What should I do?

Answer (score 0):

You say:
*once I select my code and I do "Export as snippet" in VS2015 it just open File Dialog to Add new Item to the project.*
You're opening a folder where you're gonna save your snippet.
Once it's opened, search the directory where you want it to be saved and just save it there.
You can't see any .snippet file in there because that directory has none, and you haven't still added any.

Comment: But I don't see any .snippet file to save within the directory. Which extension should I select? :(

Answer (score 0):

yes, it's all right.
you don't see .snippet files because you still don't have any, of your making.
just do as it says, add a new file with extensions .snippet.
if you can't, as a workaround, just add a new text file in that directory, and change its extension from .txt to .snippet.
Once the dialog wndows opens, you should be able to see the file and overwrite it.

Comment: It doesn't works! Even if I "add" (why I should add a file there? must be global) a .snippet, later I can't see it. Also, I can't open it...

Answer (score 0):

If you don't see any .snippet file then there might be any issue with installation. Otherwise, you should be seeing it. Enabling "SHOW HIDDEN FILES" might work.

Comment: These link are also helpful in this context:
[link] (https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms165394.aspx)
[link] (https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/customization/userdefinedsnippets)

Comment: "SHOW HIDDEN FILES" where? On VS2015? On my OS? I've already enable it.

Comment: What exactly happens when you add a new snippet?

Comment: Check this out if it solves your problem.


1. Go to Tools > Code Snippets Manager

2. Select Visual C# from the drop down menu

3. Click Add

4. Select the NetFx30 directory containing the code snippets


If in step 3 "ADD" doesn't work, you can try import.

Comment: And what should it change? I already have those folders added/imported. Nothing change....